# Can we write more than one get/post custom methods in webAPIController?? If so how to pass string parameter to that customized method?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, routes

i am new to WebApi and MVC....please help me to go forward. 
Below is the scenario in which i am facing an issue.

In WebApi Controller i want to write custom/userdefined get/post method 
and i want to pass string parameter as an argument.
but its throwing an error....
it is by defaultly accepting only integer parameter.

below is the method i need to add to webapicontroller.

```
[HttpGet]
public bool IsExists(string email)
{
//code: It will return true if email already exists else returns false.
}
```

even i added the custom routing in webApi.config file before the default API routing.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "CustomApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{Controller}/{Action}/{email:string}",
     defaults: null
);
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#why) if you are using WebApi 2:

```
[Route("api/emails/exists/{email}")]
[HttpGet]
public bool IsExists(string email)
{
//code: It will return true if email already exists else returns false.
}
```

This will take the value passed in `{email}` and pass it in the method.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
Below  is the code which i have changed in webAPIController.
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/ApplicationAPI/isExists/{email}")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        private bool isExists(string email)
       {
       //code
       }   
  
And in Service.js for calling the above action method.
        this.isExists = function (email) {
        return $http.get("/api/ApplicationAPI/isExists/"+ email); }

Comment: But i am getting an error like:
Error:5:The best overloaded method match for '~/Controllers.ApplicationAPIController.isExists(string)' has some invalid arguments 
Error:6: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just as a check can you change your `{ return $http.get("/api/ApplicationAPI/isExists/"+ email); }` to a hardcoded email address for a test? It looks like the method is getting called but with a int for some reason. Maybe something like `{ return $http.get("/api/ApplicationAPI/isExists/myemail@mydomain.xyz"); }`

Answer (score 1):

Although this references [WebApi2 route constraints](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints), ":string" is not a valid constraint by default.

Try removing the :string from your route definition.